# How can I redirect? dompdf generates an invoice but redirect doesn't take place

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I redirect? dompdf generates an invoice but redirect doesn't take place, how can I redirect after pdf file is generated? The page only gets blank and does nothing after the pdf file is generated.

```php
<?php

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])){
        $USER_ID = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];    
    }else{
        header('location:../eProject/login.php');
    }

    // Include autoloader 
    require_once 'vendor/dompdf/autoload.inc.php'; 

    // Reference the Dompdf namespace 
    use Dompdf\Dompdf; 

    // Instantiate and use the dompdf class 
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();

    ?>


    <?php
    $conn = oci_connect('EXAMPLE', 'utsav', '//localhost/xe'); 
    // Load content from html file 
    $html = file_get_contents("invoice.html"); 
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html); 
    $file_name = 'invoice' . '.pdf';

    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation 
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape'); 

    // Render the HTML as PDF 
    $dompdf->render();
    $file = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents($file_name, $file);

    // Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview) 
    $dompdf->stream("Cleckhuddersfax", array("Attachment" => 1));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">location.replace('index.php')</script>
```

Comment: A server can send only one response to a client's request. You can either send the PDF, or you can send HTML with a redirect, but not both.

Comment: Ditto the above. And if anything here you're in danger of invalidating the PDF output by appending a HTML script tag to the bottom of it